# Flux & async communication with websockets

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, promise, ecmascript-6, websocket

I want to arrange async server-client communication with websockets and vanilla flux architecture. There is an excellent article about "[Async Server-Side Communication with the Flux Architecture](http://mjw56.github.io/handling-asynchronous-data-flow-in-flux/index.html)". I gonna implement it analogue with SockJS and ES6 promises:

**TodoActionCreator.js**

```
import { dispatchAsync } from '../AppDispatcher';
import ActionTypes from '../constants/ActionTypes';
import TodoService from '../services/TodoService'

export function addTodo(text) {
  var that = this;
  TodoService.addTodo({text: text}).then(function(todo) {
    that.dispatch(ActionTypes.ADD_TODO, todo);
  });
}
```

**TodoService.js**

```
import WebSocketWrapper from '../communication/WebSocketWrapper';

export function addTodo(todo) {
    //maybe do something with todos before send them to the server
    return WebSocketWrapper.send(todo);
}
```

**WebSocketWrapper.js**

```
/**
 * Due fact that SockJS provide raw websocket API and do not implement pub/sub, we need to do wrapper, which will corellate request/response
 */
import SockJS from 'sockjs-client';
import selectn from 'selectn';

var responseDeffers = {},
    requestId = 1;

var webSocketWrapper = {

    join: function(url) {
        this.ws = new SockJS(url);
        this.ws.onopen = this.onOpen;
        this.ws.onmessage = this.onMessage;
        this.ws.onclose = this.onClose;
        this.ws.onerror = this.onError;
    },

    onMessage: function(message) {
        let requestId = selectn('message.data.request_id');
        if (!requestId) return;
        //resolve or reject the promise which is kept in ActionCreator
        if (message.data.result === 'Ok') resolveRequest(requestId, message);
        else rejectRequest(requestId, message.error);
    },

    /**
     * Return Promise, which will be resolved/rejected on server response with the same requestId
     */
    send: function(request) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            //npm run build
            // cache resolve/reject function to be able to invoke themn on server response
            responseDeffers[requestId++] = {
                resovle,
                reject
            };
            //send message via websockets
            if (this.ws.readyState == this.ws.OPEN) {
                this.ws.send(JSON.stringify(request));
            } else {
                reject('Websocket connection is closed');
            }
        });
    },

    resolveRequest: function(requestId, message) {
        let response = JSON.parse(message.data);
        responseDeffers[request_id].resolve(response);
        delete responseDeffers[request_id];
    },

    rejectRequest: function(requestId, message) {
        responseDeffers[requestId].reject(message);
    },

    onOpen: function() {},

    oClose: function() {},

    onError: function(e) {}
}

webSocketWrapper.join('http://localhost:3000/sjs');

export default webSocketWrapper;
```

Comment: So I was about to write a very detailed review on this code until I noticed that the code doesn't look valid. Would you mind going over your code first.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer yeah, sure. Give me an hour pls. I was in hurry, so haven't chance to ran it first. Actually the question is about approach, but I definitely want to make it valid

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer updated